# Issue validating a jtextfield Java

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield

It was working yesterday unless I forgot to save my changes, and I can't figure out what's wrong with it. I want it to allow numbers, commas and full stops.

```
textField_FlightPrice = new JTextField();
        textField_FlightPrice.setColumns(10);
        textField_FlightPrice.setBounds(152, 291, 273, 22);
        contentPane.add(textField_FlightPrice);
        textField_FlightPrice.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent g) {
                // allows only numbers, , ., back space, delete, and slash.
                char c = g.getKeyChar();
                if ((c < '0') || (c > '9') && (c != ',') && (c != '.') && (c != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) && (c != KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)
                        && (c != KeyEvent.VK_SLASH)) {
                    g.consume(); // ignore event
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. What happens if you paste text into the text field? A KeyListener won't handle it. Instead use a `JFormattedTextField` (which supports masks for valid characters) or a `DocumentFilter` (which allows you to edit as text is added to the Document). Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are section on `How to Use Formatted Text Fields` and `Text Component Features` (which has examples of a DocumentFilter) to get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate it, reading through it now! I'm still curious though, do you know what I was doing wrong with the above cos i deffo had it working

Comment: `I can't figure out what's wrong` - general tip. Don't use a single if statement to test for all valid vaules. Instead break it up into multiple if conditions then it is easer to add debug code to see where the test if failing. For example you have something like `if (c is a number) return;`. Then you have `if (c is "." or ",") return;`

Comment: ah yeah, true, i'll start splitting them up from now on cos I have multiple validation like this to do :D thanks

Comment: Also, check out the `Character.isDigit(...)` method to simplify the first check.